Broken encoding in the received Json Android Retrofit2
Could you suggest any solutions to the problem? Upon request, I received the following message:
Unexpected JSON token at offset 0: Expected start of the array '[', but had '' instead at path: $JSON input: ~����������t������t5��������)����s�?��v���������sJ0d�%���|x��3ސ�4�z�r

My Retrofit builder looks like this:
Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl(BASE_URL_API)
    .addConverterFactory(json.asConverterFactory("application/json; charset=UTF8".toMediaType()))
    .addCallAdapterFactory(ApiResponseCallAdapterFactory.create())
    .build()

When you try to access the URL through the browser, the data is displayed correctly, as well as there are no problems with other requests. What could be the problem?

You appear to be receiving some sort of binary format, not JSON. You might consider adding the OkHttp logging interceptor to your Retrofit configuration, then seeing what MIME type your server is putting on the response or if there are other things in the HTTP response headers that may give you some clues.

I would try to use the GSON converter as Retrofit says on their website.  Have a go and probably will be easier.

@CommonsWare I checked the headers and realized that the request response uses Brotli encoding. After searching for information, I found the OkHttp BrotliInterceptor. I think it should solve the problem? There is no way to check it now

I have not used Brotli, but what you describe sounds plausible. Good luck!

The JSON responses I received were encrypted in Brotli, I got this information from the header.
You can decrypt the data using the following: okhttp-brotli
